# How to get certain String values in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
String [] array=new String[7];

array[0]="a";
array[1]="b";
array[2]="c";
array[3]="d";
array[4]="e";
array[5]="f";
array[6]="g";

for (int i=0;i<array.Length;i++){
  if(array[i].equals("b")) {
        // check array from the first one and when it is "b" starts
        // to print the string value till "e"
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
    if (array[i].equals("e"))
        break;
}
```

I have an array of Strings and i want to print the the all the string values when it hits "b" and stop at "e"

Is there anyway i can do that ?

My expected outcome is :

```
b
c
d
e
```

Comment: the way you fill your array is horrible , prefer to use `new String[]{"a","b","c", ....}`

Comment: use loop to fill array elements, and why are you adding elements on the same index?

Comment: also `array.Length` (L is uppercase) is not valid java

Comment: @Lino serious bro?? Im just trying to write a demo here of course is not my actual code lol

Comment: @JasonWEI I am serious. You should provide demo code that *does* compile, that people can copy, to maybe reproduce your problem. This site is not a "I have a problem, pls help"-site, so you should also offer us something we can work with, without further interpreting

Comment: @Lino, `{"a", "b", "c", ...}` (as an array initializer) is less horrible :)

Comment: @Andrew totally forgot about that one, that's even better ;)

Answer (score 3):

A Java-9 solution would be:

```
Arrays.stream(array)
      .dropWhile(e -> !"b".equals(e))
      .takeWhile(e -> !"f".equals(e))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Glorious, but potentially horrible inefficient, due to the extra overhead :)

Comment: @Lino `dropWhile` and `takeWhile()` are generally cheap operations on sequential pipelines. I wouldn't worry about performance for now until otherwise noticed.

Comment: Of course with this small set of data this works like a charm, but it could explode when 1) the datasource is bigger and 2) the conditions never match e.g. by not having the desired element

Answer (score 3):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);

list.subList(list.indexOf("b"), list.indexOf("e") + 1)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

*assuming that both `"b"` and `"e"` are present in the array (1) and `"e"` comes after `"b"` (2).

Comment: I was going for this but using  `String.substring` with `String.join("", array)` but the idea is the same.

Comment: creating a `new ArrayList<>()` is not needed an can be omitted

Answer (score 2):

Simply find start and end indexes and iterate over it -

```
List<String> arrList = Arrays.asList(arr);
int indexOfB = arrList.indexOf("b"); 
int indexOfE = arrList.indexOf("e");
for(int i =indexOfB; i<=indexOfE; i++){
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: `ArrayUtils` is not in the Standard Java language, maybe add a link to apache commons

Comment: And I am pretty sure you can get a subset of the array from `indexOfB` to `indexOfE` with a library that provided that kind of method. Instead of the loop

Comment: that's what I am suggesting (but without the use of a third-party library)

Comment: @Andrew, check the updated answer with out using third party.

Comment: What is the algorithm used by `ArrayUtils.indexOf` ? What if you have twice the same value ? It is not precise in [the documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-) if this return the first occurence or any... PS: That edit is what Andrew did but using two different instance of `List`.

Comment: @DerickDaniel, not it is identical to mine :) thought, you did `Arrays.asList(arr)` twice

Comment: @Andrew, corrected , din't see your answer before :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag to know the first occurence has been found to know if you need to print the current value.

```
String[] array = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"};

boolean toPrint = false;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i].equals("b")) //Find `b`, flag fo printing
        toPrint = true;

    if(toPrint) 
        System.out.println(array[i]);

    if (array[i].equals("e")) //Find `e`, break the loop
        break;
}
```

This will simply set a boolean to `true` when the begining occurs and will print every values until the second value is found. Then it will break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can find and save index of 'b'  in a variable and the same for 'e', after that compare `if(indexB <= indexE)` and if is true print all from b until to e

**EDIT:**

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {

    String[] array = new String[]{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"};

    bigFor: for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        if (array[i].equals("b")) {

            for(int x = i; x < array.length; x++) {

                System.out.println(array[x]);

                if(array[x].equals("e")) {

                    break bigFor;

                }   
            }   
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: this might be slow, because you have to first iterate the array 2 times, for finding out the indeces, and then again for the printing

Comment: I know, but is the most simple and safe method for someone who is beginner.

Comment: well it doesn't help you when you learn something "bad" from the beginning, why not do it the correct way from the start?

Comment: There is nothing bad. You can improve your knowledge and in time your skill to write efficient code.

Comment: Yes it is a bad logic because this logic stops at "this works". Since you are iterating an array to find a first value, keep looking for the second value. Then why using boolean to print based on the values readed. See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50411097/4391450) that used your logic but improved.

Comment: what about now?

Comment: 2 loops don't improve your answer, as you're misusing them (the outer loop just iterates until it has found `"b"`)

Comment: In the most bad case, both for is like one who does from 0 to length.